# Angular Elements (custom element) is not visible in the DOM

Tags: angular, custom-element, angular-elements

I have created a sample application to try and show a simple web component in Angular using Angular Elements. I am not facing any error in the console but my custom element is not visible in the browser DOM either. I am running Angular version 12.2.2 on Linux (Ubuntu) on Chrome Broswer.

This is my app.module.ts According to the Angular Elements doc my ngDoBootstrap function is correct.

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [
    BookComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }
  
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const myCustomElement = createCustomElement(BookComponent, { injector: this.injector});
    window.customElements.define('app-book', myCustomElement);
  }
}
```

and my Book Component is also simple where I am just displaying a title

book.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Booking App';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

book.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    {{ title }}
  </div>
```

This is my package.json where I have my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "document-register-element": "^1.8.1",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^12.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone help me identify what is that I am doing wrong ? I have attached an image of the DOM as well. [image]

Comment: `window.customElements.define('app-book', myCustomElement);` just defines the element. You have to put the `<app-book>` tag in the html somewhere to use it.

Comment: Well that does work ! But if I am bootstrapping the component will it not load by default on localhost:4200. ?

Comment: I was following this post @peinearydevelopment https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58 and there is nothing mentioned of adding the tag in the html since the component selector is the same.

Comment: Look at [this part of the article](https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58#5de3) where it discusses updating the index.html and they are adding the tags for their custom elements into the html there.